# Detect BSSID changes Constantly

Tags: android

I am developing an android application that is supposed to **constantly** check the BSSID of the access point to which the phone is connected, knowing that the phone will always be connected to one network but may connect to multiple access points (Not at the same time, of course) since the building is big. I used a BroadcastReceiver but to check whether the phone got connected to a different access point, I have to close the application and run it again to get the updated BSSID. I want the application to constantly check and update the UI with the new BSSID without me having to close the application and open it again. Do you have any idea how I can do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have sucessfully used this in the past to monitor for WiFi connection changes:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
        NetworkInfo wifiInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        // etc
    }
}
}
```

Just register your receiver in onResume() and unregister it in onPause() and you should be good to go.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();       

    IntentFilter connectivityFilter = new IntentFilter();
    connectivityFilter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
    registerReceiver(your_broadcast_receiver, connectivityFilter);
}
```